# Performance difference while using shared data-structure instead of private data-structure in OpenMP

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I've been working on OpenMP and trying to figure out why there is a performance drop when keeping an array as shared instead of private. Any input would be helpful.

When the array is shared, it takes about 65ms to run while if it is made private then it takes about 38ms on an Intel Xeon E5540 CPU. The following code was compiled on Ubuntu with GCC 4.4.3

I don't think it's due to false sharing since only read operations are performed on the array elements.

```
#define PI 3.14159265
#define large 1000000

double e[large];

int main() {
    int i,j,k,m;
    timeval t1,t2;

    double elapsedtime;
    omp_set_num_threads(16);
    for(i=0;i<large;i++) {
        e[i]=rand();
    }

    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(e)   
//  #pragma omp parallel for private(i,e)


    for(i=0;i<large;i++) {
        fmodf((exp(log((sin(e[i]*PI/180)+cos((e[i]*2)*PI/180))*10))*PI),3.0);
        fmodf((exp(log((sin(e[i]*PI/180)+cos((e[i]*2)*PI/180))*10))*PI),3.0);
        fmodf((exp(log((sin(e[i]*PI/180)+cos((e[i]*2)*PI/180))*10))*PI),3.0);
    }

    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    elapsedtime = (t2.tv_sec*1000000 + t2.tv_usec) - (t1.tv_sec * 1000000 + t1.tv_usec);
    printf("%f ",elapsedtime/1000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are your timings reliable?

Comment: You mean that "only read operations are performed" **during the parallel section**, however you write to the array before that, possibly leaving it modified in the cache. In that case, I suspect read sharing would take longer to work since you'll need to evict the modified data first. For the sake of checking - can you increase large so it can't fit in your last-level cache?

Comment: @steabert : The timings should be reliable. I ran it a few hundred times when the system wasn't loaded.

Comment: @Leeor : I think you might be on the right track. The differences were negligible when the write section was commented out. I increased 'large' by a factor of 10 and the times increased by approximately the same factor. The results are the same if I perform an update on every element.(e[i]*=math operations). Could you tell me what's going on here? Is there a way to keep the cache updated before the parallel section?

Comment: I guess by the number of threads used that you either have a dual-CPU system with HyperThreading on or a quad-CPU system with HT off. What you observe is a typical NUMA behaviour - with private arrays you have 2x or 4x the memory bandwidth, hence faster execution.

Comment: @Nithin: I'm not sure if that's the problem. The array is "updated", it's just that part of it may be sitting in cache. I'm not sure what MESI protocol your CPU is implementing, but if it encounters a modified line it has to move the value either to a lower cache or to memory - I was guessing you suffer from that latency. To check, define another large array, and right before you mark the start time and enter the parallel section - sweep over it with reads only (sum the values or something). If it's big enough it would clear all cached lines that belong to e, doing all the writebacks.

Comment: @HristoIliev I'm using a dual-CPU each with a quad-core with HT on. Is it because threads on one CPU or core is using the cache on another? I need to know if shared variables use some form of locking mechanism. Any suggestions for further reading? Also, why is there no performance difference if the array was uninitialized?

Comment: @Leeor I tried what you suggested but it doesn't change any performance parameters.

Comment: It's a bit complex to be explained in a comment but it has to do with how memory is managed on modern OSes. Uninitialised global data goes to the `.bss` section of the ELF executable and is initially copy-on-write (CoW) mapped to a single page in the kernel containing all zeros. `private` variables are also uninitialised and usually get the same treatment as the `.bss` if the the array is sufficiently large. I'll post a longer comment when I find time to do so.

Comment: @HristoIliev : Okay. I was also wondering why shared and threadprivate has approximately the same performance but making the array firstprivate seems to slow it down. Any ideas?

Comment: `firstprivate` copies the data from the original variable to all the private copies on entry into the parallel region. After that the private arrays occupy a lot of physical memory and cache space instead of all being mapped to the zero page.

Comment: @HristoIliev Let's say that I've initialized data incase of `firstprivate` and `threadprivate` variables. I'm assuming that `firstprivate` variables would be local to each thread on the stack whereas `threadprivate` variables would be global or thread local storage. Wouldn't both consume the same amount of memory? Why would there be a performance difference when using them?

Comment: If you just make `e` thread-private in your original code, then only the copy in the main thread would get initialised. The other copies would still be uninitialised. If you make it `firstprivate` then all copies would be written over by the data copy procedure.

Comment: @HristoIliev Is there a difference between using `firstprivate` and `threadprivate` with `copyin` other than where the variables are created and initialized?  Here are the timings I'm getting : 1)`shared(e)` 49.11   2)`firstprivate(e)` 56.44   3)`threadprivate(e) with copyin` 108.87

Comment: `threadprivate` variables are addressed differently than `(first)private` variables. It takes more instructions (and cycles) to access an element of a `threadprivate` array hence it's slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to get rid of global variable. That's your code, modified in several places.

```
//timings.cpp
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PI 3.14159265
#define large 100000

int main() {
    int i;
    timeval t1,t2;

    double elapsedtime;
    bool b=false;

    double e[large];
    double p[large];

    omp_set_num_threads(1);
    for(i=0;i<large;i++) {
        e[i]=9.0;
    }

   /* for(i=0;i<large;i++) {
       p[i]=9.0;
    }*/

     gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
  #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(b) private(i) shared(e)
  //#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(b) private(e,i)
     for(i=0;i<large;i++) {
        if (!b)
        {
            printf("e[i]=%f, e address: %p, n=%d\n",e[i],&e,omp_get_thread_num());
            b=true;
        }
        fmodf((exp(log((sin(e[i]*PI/180)+cos((e[i]*2)*PI/180))*10))*PI),3.0);
        fmodf((exp(log((sin(e[i]*PI/180)+cos((e[i]*2)*PI/180))*10))*PI),3.0);
        fmodf((exp(log((sin(e[i]*PI/180)+cos((e[i]*2)*PI/180))*10))*PI),3.0);
        fmodf((exp(log((sin(e[i]*PI/180)+cos((e[i]*2)*PI/180))*10))*PI),3.0);
        fmodf((exp(log((sin(e[i]*PI/180)+cos((e[i]*2)*PI/180))*10))*PI),3.0);
        fmodf((exp(log((sin(e[i]*PI/180)+cos((e[i]*2)*PI/180))*10))*PI),3.0);
        fmodf((exp(log((sin(e[i]*PI/180)+cos((e[i]*2)*PI/180))*10))*PI),3.0);
        fmodf((exp(log((sin(e[i]*PI/180)+cos((e[i]*2)*PI/180))*10))*PI),3.0);
        fmodf((exp(log((sin(e[i]*PI/180)+cos((e[i]*2)*PI/180))*10))*PI),3.0);
    }

    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    elapsedtime = (t2.tv_sec*1000000 + t2.tv_usec) - (t1.tv_sec * 1000000 + t1.tv_usec);
    printf("%f ",elapsedtime/1000);
    return 0;
}
```

We shall run it through script "1.sh" to automatically measure timings,

```
#/bin/bash
sed -i '/parallel/ s,#,//#,g' timings.cpp
sed -i '/parallel/ s,////#,#,g' timings.cpp
g++ -O0 -fopenmp timings.cpp -o timings
> time1.txt
for loopvar in {1..10}
do
if [ "$loopvar" -eq 1 ]
then
./timings >> time1.txt;
cat time1.txt;
echo;
else
./timings | tail -1 >> time1.txt;
fi
done
echo "---------"
echo "Total time:"
echo `tail -1 time1.txt | sed s/' '/'+'/g | sed s/$/0/ | bc -li | tail -1`/`tail -1 time1.txt| wc -w | sed s/$/.0/` | bc -li | tail -1
```

Here are testing results (Intel@ Core 2 Duo E8300):

1) #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(b) private(i) shared(e)

```
user@comp:~ ./1.sh
Total time:
152.96380000000000000000
```

We have strange latencies.
E.g. output:

```
e[i]=9.000000, e address: 0x7fffb67c6960, n=0
e[i]=9.000000, e address: 0x7fffb67c6960, n=7
e[i]=9.000000, e address: 0x7fffb67c6960, n=8
//etc..
```

**Note the address - it's the same for all arrays (so it is called *shared*)**

2) #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(e,b) private(i)

```
user@comp:~ ./1.sh
Total time:
157.48220000000000000000
```

We have copying of data e (firstprivate) to each thread
E.g. output:

```
e[i]=9.000000, e address: 0x7ff93c4238e0, n=1
e[i]=9.000000, e address: 0x7ff939c1e8e0, n=6
e[i]=9.000000, e address: 0x7ff93ac208e0, n=4
```

3) #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(b) private(e,i)

```
Total time:
123.97110000000000000000
```

No copying of data, only allocation (private are used uninitialized)
E.g. output:

```
 e[i]=0.000000, e address: 0x7fca98bdb8e0, n=1
 e[i]=0.000000, e address: 0x7fffa2d10090, n=0
 e[i]=0.000000, e address: 0x7fca983da8e0, n=2
```

Here we have different addresses, but all **e** values contain memory garbage (nills are likely due to mmap memory page preallocation).

To see, that firstprivate(e) is slower because of copying of arrays, let's comment out all calculations (lines with "fmodf")
// #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(b) private(i) shared(e)

```
Total time:
9.69700000000000000000
```

// #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(e,b) private(i)

```
Total time:
12.83000000000000000000
```

// #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(b) private(i,e)

```
Total time:
9.34880000000000000000
```

Firstprivate(e) is slow because of copying array.
Shared(e) is slow because of calculation lines.

Compile with -O3 -ftree-vectorize slightly decreases time of shared:

// #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(b) private(i) shared(e)

```
user@comp:~ ./1.sh
Total time:
141.38330000000000000000
```

// #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(b) private(e,i)

```
Total time:
121.80390000000000000000
```

Using schedule(static, 256) doesn't make the trick.

Let's continue with -O0 option turned on.
Comment out array filling: // e[i]=9.0;

// #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(b) private(i) shared(e)

```
Total time:
121.40780000000000000000
```

// #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(b) private(e,i)

```
Total time:
122.33990000000000000000
```

So, "shared" is slower because of "private" data were used uninitialized (as proposed by commenters).

Let's see the dependence on thread number:

```
4threads
shared
Total time:
156.95030000000000000000
private
Total time:
121.11390000000000000000

2threads
shared
Total time:
155.96970000000000000000
private
Total time:
126.62130000000000000000

1thread (perfomance goes down ca. twice, I have 2-core machine)
shared
Total time:
283.06280000000000000000
private
Total time:
229.37680000000000000000
```

To compile this with 1.sh, I manually discomented both "parallel for" lines to give 1.sh comment out both of them.

```
**1thread without parallel, initialized e[i]**
Total time:
281.22040000000000000000

**1thread without parallel, uninitialized e[i]** 
Total time:
231.66060000000000000000
```

So, it's not OpenMP issue, but memory/cache using issue.
Generation of asm code with

```
g++ -O0 -S timings.cpp
```

in both cases gives two differences: one, that can be neglected, in label LC numeration, the other, that one label (L3) contains not 1, but 5 asm lines, when initializing **e** array:

```
L3:
movl    -800060(%rbp), %eax
movslq  %eax, %rdx
movabsq $4621256167635550208, %rax
movq    %rax, -800016(%rbp,%rdx,8)
```

(where initialization occures) and common line:
`addl   $1, -800060(%rbp)`

So, it seems like cache issue.

That's not an answer, you can use the code above to study the problem further,

Comment: Yes, I believe you're right. I'd come to a similar conclusion. Initialization and copying is where the extra time goes. When using the array as `threadprivate`, the performance worsens. Thank you for the confirmation.